# Minified React with Webpack is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, webpack

I am developing a web app in React using Webpack. I have followed [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build) to generate bundle.js in production mode, but it is not working. I always get:

> Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development
> build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to
> use the production build which skips development warnings and is
> faster.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');//FOR CSS

var config = {
    devtool:'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/, 
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css', {allChunks: false}),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env':{
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
          }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compress:{
            warnings: true
          }
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

And this is the package.json file I am using:

```
{
  "name": "p12uibetajsx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack -d",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1",
    "webpack-combine-loaders": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.0.21",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-combine-loaders": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Is there anything else I need to configure? Am I  missing something?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to run your webpack with `NODE_ENV=production`, like for example: `NODE_ENV=production webpack` ?

Comment: Yes Marcel, I have tried but I get the message that NODE_ENV is not a recognized command,

Comment: Ah, so you're on Windows?  Then try to set the env variable first and run webpack after. So `SET NODE_ENV=production` and then `webpack`. See if that works.

Comment: he is doing that with the DefinePlugin already...

Comment: Yes I am using Windows, but still getting the warning message setting the variable first. 

I have set it this way:

npm set NODE_ENV=production
set NODE_ENV=production

Comment: Of course, @luschn is absolutely right. Ok, next question: The warning you get in the browser console after you build it with `npm run build` ?

Comment: Yes, I use npm run build and then in the browser when I load the web I get the warning mentioned above.

Comment: @JSP749 Sorry, then I have no idea what's wrong here. I just build a project with your package and webpack configs and I get no warnings whatsoever. Weird.  Maybe \a quick reset of your npm modules helps? `rm -r node_modules && npm install`

Comment: I have tried that and now it works, maybe was something cached, thank you!!

Comment: @JSP749 Yeah, the good old reset works wonders sometimes. Glad it helped. Happy Coding! :-)